# Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am using

1. UBUNTU 20
2. Vagrant 2.2.9
3. Homestead release branch
4. Composer version 1

After installing vagrant and homestead.
Whenever I hit any laravel project then I got this error.

> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass()

I also update my PHP version using these below commands

```
 vagrant ssh

 sudo update-alternatives --config PHP


 sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
 sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.1
 sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.1
 sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize7.1
 sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config7.1
```

After this when I check PHP version then it shows **7.1**

**I don't know after changing the PHP version which service I need to restart?**

Answer (score 2):

> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass()

it simply means that the method is no longer supported in PHP 8.

Just open your Homestead.yaml file and add your PHP version in the sites section.

```
-map: homestead.test
 to: /home/vagrant/code/public
 php: "7.1" #set the PHP version here
```

And run

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

mmm put a phpinfo() in your index and tell me your results. I run in homestead the following command "php71" and the output of "php -v" is as expected

> PHP 7.1.33-37+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 1 2021
> 11:51:55) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
> v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.1.33-37+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

However in my phpinfo() located in the index.php of the project the output is PHP Version 8.0.5 :S